# Php checkbox is checked, then mysql update 1, and if not checked mysql update 0

Tags: php, mysql

```
echo "<form method='POST' action=''><br>";
$query = mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
$query = mysql_query("
  SELECT * FROM pages WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'
") or die(mysql_error());

while($pagek = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $name = $pagek['page_name'];
  $pageid = $pagek['page_id'];
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="page_ids[]" value="'.$pageid.'">'
      .$name
      ."<br>";
}

echo "<br>
      <input type='submit'
             value='Adatok frissítése'
             name ='adat'
             class='button small radius center black'
      >";
echo "</form>";

foreach($_POST['page_ids'] as $page){
  if ($page){
    mysql_query("
      UPDATE pages
      SET    page_value = '0'
      WHERE  user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'
    ");
    mysql_query("
      UPDATE pages
      SET    page_value = '1'
      WHERE  user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'
         AND page_id = '$page'
    ");
  }
}
```

I like, then if Which checkbox is checked this mysql update 1, and more than 0.

This code is not good, here in only a site update on getting the rest are zero, and you can always choose a site

Comment: remove if($_POST['adat']) is useless

Comment: not a problem, I accidentally left inside

Answer (score 3):

**First!**

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Seriously, your code contains a serious vulnerability called **[SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/871050)**. If you don't fix it, your website can and *will* be compromised very easily.

---

Unchecked checkboxes **do not get submitted at all**. So basically, your server won't see anything.

To take that into account, what you should do is to **set it to 0 by default**, unconditionally, and *then*, if the checkbox was checked, set it to 1.

Yes, it does require you to possible do 2 queries in a request, but it's the only way to ensure you get the result you need.

Comment: And what about: `isset($_POST['checkbox'])` instead? Combined with prepared statements this will safely return the desired value: 1 if it's checked and 0 if it isn't.

Comment: @STTLCU: Sure. but if you noticed, he has *multiple* checkboxes, so setting all the fields to 0, and then setting them to one on a one-by-one basis is feasible. And in my opinion, still the best solution.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){

      mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET page_value = '1' WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['user_id']} AND page_id = '$page'");
    }
    else{
    mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET page_value = '0' WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['user_id']} AND page_id = '$page'");
    }

So not working, just 1 positions update, with 0 does not address

Answer (score 3):

You could use `isset()` to see if the checkbox has been checked.

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
{
    $update = 1;
}
else
{
    $update = 0;
}
```

Then add $update to your query. Hope this helps.

Comment: not addressed as an array of checkboxes so only 1 positions detected with 0

Answer (score 0):

Try $_SESSION vars like:

```
UPDATE pages SET page_value = '0' WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
UPDATE pages SET page_value = '1' WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['user_id']} AND page_id = '$page'
```

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` for more security:

```
$pages = mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($_POST['page_ids']));

foreach($pages as $page) {
   // action
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is array. Now array is serialized. Try now. You must not use mysql_real_escape_string, it is just more secure

Comment: So no good whatever I choose to only 1 to update to a 0 for some reason does not get it

Comment: Did you get any error? Or pages column affected? `var_dump($_POST['page_ids']);` and `var_dump($_SESSION);` please

Comment: I get an error, I did what you asked and the session is for the POST has a value, so you can not go wrong with

Comment: good location for update query, and only if the checkbox is not selected, then the page does not update 0

Answer (score 0):

Solve the task in the right solution:

```
  echo "<form method='POST' action=''><br>";
    $query = mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'  ") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">Nincs megjeleníthető Facebook oldalad! Kérlek jelentkezz be az FB Login menüpont alatt!</td></tr>";
        } else {
            echo "<u>Kérem válassza ki melyik oldalaira szeretne képet feltölteni!</u><br><br><br>";

            while($pagek = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $name = $pagek['page_name'];
                $pageid = $pagek['page_id'];
                 echo '<input type="checkbox" name="page_ids[]" value="'.$pageid.'">'.$name."<br>"; 

                                            }           

            echo "<br><input type='submit' value='Adatok frissítése' name ='adat' class='button small radius center black'>";


            echo"</form>";




            if($_POST['adat']){
            mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET page_value = '0' WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]' ");


            foreach($_POST['page_ids'] as $page){
                $pa = $page;

                    if ($pa){
                        mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET page_value = '1' WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'  AND page_id = '$page'  ");
                            }

                                                }   
                            }

                        }
                        }
```